# Will Mountain Lion's Time Machine read data from a NAS and back it up to an external USB drive?

Tags: time-machine, macos

So, I have most of my data on a NAS.

Can I configure time machine to backup both my iMac's internal drive as well as my data stored on a NAS? All of the backups are to be stored on an USB drive attached to my iMac.

I'm running Mountain Lion. The NAS I have is here:

http://www.buffalotech.com/products/network-storage/home-and-small-office-nas/linkstation-pro-duo-1

I'm not sure which protocol I'm using right now, but it supports AFP.

Comment: Does your NAS mount as a network share?  If so, what transfer protocol does it use?

Comment: Yes, it's a network share. Please see my edits, and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Time Machine always backs up all mounted volumes connected to the Mac via USB/FireWire/Thunderbolt, it can't backup network volumes like a NAS.

As it seems, this is not mentioned anywhere in Apple's support documents, but here's a good [Time Machine FAQ](http://pondini.org/TM/2.html) made by a user.

Comment: Wow!!! That's fantastic...I wish Apple would add more options to Timemachine so you'd know what's it's actually doing. What's the recovery process like if you need to restore the NAS from the Timemachine backup?

Comment: well, you open your mounted NAS in Finder and enter Time Machine (click the icon in the dock or select from menubar icon) and go back in time as usual.

Comment: I checked my Timemachine backup folder and the NAS isn't there only "Macintosh HD"...

Comment: Is the NAS maybe added automatically to the exclude list in the Time Machine options?

Comment: Nope. It's not on the excluded list. Are you sure Time Machine can back up a NAS?

Comment: huge sorry from my side, I had a look at all the support documents from Apple and they all just mention "mounted volumes" and nowhere do a distinction between local and network mounted volumes. I've corrected the answer, backup FROM network volumes is not possible with Time Machine :-(

Comment: Thanks for getting down to the bottom of this for me. It's a shame... Time Machine is very simple and easy to use, but that's also it's downfall. Maybe Automator has some kind of File sync thing I can use and schedule.